# Node.Js error for socket Hangup

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

My question is as follows :

abc lambda triggering another lambda(named : khjj)
 Everything is going fine for me only the thing is that in the cloudwatch logs or even in locally if I run the abc lambda function to trigger the khjj lambda, I am getting socket hangup error after my requests.

My abc lambda reads one data from a dynamo db table and row by row triggers the khjj function, the code in abc lambda is :

```
    var sendData = module.exports = {
     data : function(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     arrayData = []

  // here table.get is a function in the same file for getting the 
    // data from the dynamo db table
    table.get("Table1").then(function(response){
    _.forEach(response, function(data){
      var obj = {};
      obj.value1 = data.value1;
      obj.value2 = data.value2;  
      obj.value3 = data.value3;
      obj.value4 = data.value4;
      obj.value5 = data.value5;
      obj.value6 = data.value6;
      obj.value7 = data.value7;
      arrayData.push(obj)
    })
    Promise.all(arrayData).then(function(objs){
      async.each(objs, function(data, callback){
        request({
          headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
          url : // here I used lambda khjj url here,
          method: 'POST',
          body: company,
          json: true
      }, function (err, res, body) {
          if(!_.isNil(err)){
            console.log(err);
            console.log('error in triggering')
          } else {
            // tried this callback as well to stop that error of socket hangup
            callback(null, 'success')
          }
          })
        }, function(err){
          console.log()
        })
      }, function(err){
         console.log(err)
      })
    }, function(err){
      console.log('error in getting data from table :', err)

    })
  resolve(true);
})
 }
```

Now the above lambda function triggering the "khjj" lambda, so there is awsServerlessExpress function I used in the "khjj" lambda function so it is getting request here in the code :

```
    app.post('/called/by/abc/lambda', function(req, 
     resp){
      check.message(request).then(function(response){
      resp.write('success')
      resp.end();
      }, function(err){
         console.log(err)
       resp.end();
    })
   })
```

The socket error is coming in the above lambda i.e. khjj, searched all over the net even stackoverflow and aws forums as well but not got any solution

Even considered this website : https://gregjs.com/javascript/2015/how-to-scrape-the-web-gently-with-node-js/

Please any help would be fine. Thanks.

CloudWatch error :

```
    2017-05-25T13:30:15.043Z    009c3110-414e-11e7-99b5-b3bd2686fba3    
    { Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:253:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:345:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback 
    (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Comment: Can you please log the stack trace to cloudwatch and provide it here?

Comment: Yes I have updated with the log error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question above, the error was coming only because somewhere in the code I was not handling promise reject properly.